# Focus tab after firing Create record event in console app

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, console

I'm firing force:createRecord event from custom lightning component in lightning service console. I used Workspace api close Tab and closing the current and firing the record event , after that where ere no tabs opened it works fine. if i open some other tabs and fire this event it refers to the wrong tab. How to refer correct tab after firing the event?

```
handleCreateRecord: function(component, event, helper) { 
    var workspaceAPI = component.find("workspace");
    workspaceAPI.getFocusedTabInfo().then(function(response) {
        var focusedTabId = response.tabId;
        workspaceAPI.closeTab({tabId: focusedTabId});
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
        console.log(error);
    });

    var selectedRecordTypeId = component.get("v.selectedRecordTypeId");
    if(selectedRecordTypeId){
        var createRecordEvent = $A.get("e.force:createRecord");
        createRecordEvent.setParams({
            "entityApiName": 'Case',
            "recordTypeId": selectedRecordTypeId, 
        });
        createRecordEvent.fire(); 
    }

}
```

Comment: Have you found the answer to this? I am facing the same problem